# Display all dates on models in the user’s timezone (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php-carbon

I have the users [timezone](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php) stored (there is `timezone` column in the `users` DB table) and I want to display **all** `$dates` attributes on **all models** in the user’s timezone, if **authenticated**.

I'm trying to find an elegant way to do this... Ideally, when there is something like this in Blade views:

```
{{ $post->created_at }}

OR

{{ $post->created_at->format('h:i:s A') }}
```

... for authenticated users it would be automatically in their timezones.

**How would you handle this?**

---

I'm thinking about creating one trait (for example, `app/Traits/UserTimezoneAware.php`) and place there [accessors](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) that will simply return `Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value)->timezone(auth()->user()->timezone)` if the current user is authenticated. For example:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Carbon\Carbon;

trait UserTimezoneAware
{
    /**
     * Get the created_at in the user's timezone.
     *
     * @param $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
    {
        if (auth()->check()) {
            return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value)->timezone(auth()->user()->timezone);
        }

        return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $value);
    }

    /**
     * Get the updated_at in the user's timezone.
     *
     * @param $value
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value) { ... }
}
```

But I'm not sure if this is good or bad to do (to create these accessros for the Laravel's `$dates`attributes)?

Also, models will have **different** attributes specified in `$dates` array: for example, `User` model can have:

```
/**
 * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'last_login_at'
];
```

and `Post` model can have:

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at',
    'approved_at',
    'deleted_at'
];
```

**Is it possible to dynamically** create accessors in trait, based on the attirbutes specified in the `$dates` array of a model that uses that trait?

Or maybe there is a better way to handle this, without accessors?

Answer (score 5):

One way (without accessors) is to use this trait:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use DateTimeInterface;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

trait UserTimezoneAware
{
    /**
     * Return a timestamp as DateTime object.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return \Illuminate\Support\Carbon
     */
    protected function asDateTime($value)
    {
        $timezone = auth()->check() ? auth()->user()->timezone : config('app.timezone');

        if ($value instanceof Carbon) {
            return $value->timezone($timezone);
        }

        if ($value instanceof DateTimeInterface) {
            return new Carbon(
                $value->format('Y-m-d H:i:s.u'), $timezone
            );
        }

        if (is_numeric($value)) {
            return Carbon::createFromTimestamp($value)->timezone($timezone);
        }

        if ($this->isStandardDateFormat($value)) {
            return Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value)->startOfDay()->timezone($timezone);
        }

        return Carbon::createFromFormat(
            str_replace('.v', '.u', $this->getDateFormat()), $value
        )->timezone($timezone);
    }
}
```

When using this trait, we are overriding `asDateTime($value)` defined in `Concerns\HasAttributes` trait (which is used in `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`).

This seems to work OK, I have not yet encountered any problems.

But I'm not sure if there are any risks or potential problems when doing this (when using this trait that overrides `asDateTime` method).