# Laravel set auto timezone for guests

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question about timezone. let's say i set a default timezone: 'UTC' on laravel. If guest of website from Russia, or if guest from India, how I can show time them with their timezone? How I can define timezone them ? Example I have post, and I show time post with: `$post->created_at` this show me default date with default timezone. How I can show this date with timezone guests from Russia, India and other countries.. ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Display all dates on models in the user’s timezone (Laravel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50768490/display-all-dates-on-models-in-the-user-s-timezone-laravel)

Answer (score 0):

You would do this via the front end. E.g. render it with moment.js that's if you want the exact date and or time.

I mostly use `$post->created_at->diffForHumans();` which will return something like 3 hours ago or 5 months ago

Comment: Yes. I use moment js, but if I I have time zone `-1 hour`, then when I create post, moment js get me: `in an hour`, when I use function: `moment(post.created_at).fromNow()`

Comment: If you use diff for humans on the blade without moment it will show the correct "time" ago regardless of timezone. If you are wanting to render it with moment you would set the timezone with something like `moment.tz.guess();` http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/guessing-user-timezone/